# iOS SWIFT Propotional values calculation

Tags: ios, swift, math

I have a func that recives first value and should return another one

the input range is 24 - (8 - 0) (Int, not more and not less)

and output should give 20 - 60

so 24 will give 20 and (all <= 8) will give 60
and ll others propotional to each other

How can i reach such a calculation?

Comment: what is 24 - (8 - 0) this range? is it 0 to  24?

Comment: it is 24 to 8 dependently to output, and less then 8 will always give 60

Comment: Check my answer. It is giving your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made method in objective c, keep main logic from it and convert to swift,

```
 - (int)calculate : (int)parameter{

   int returnParameter;

if (parameter < 8) {

    returnParameter = 60;
}
else{

    returnParameter = 20 + ((24 - parameter) * 2.5);

}

NSLog(@"return value : %d",returnParameter);

return returnParameter;


}
```

Pass parameter between 0 to 24 and it will return 60 to 20 respectively as per your need.

You should use double or float for more accuracy! because this will convert in integer if fraction is there!

**Update in swift :**

something like this,

```
func GetValue(param: Int) -> Int
{
    var Ret = Int()

    if param < 8
    {
        Ret = 60
    }else{

        Ret = 20 + Int(Double(24 - Double(param)) * 2.5)
    }

    if param > 24
    {
        Ret = 8
    }

    return Ret
}
```

Ready to swift 2.1

Hope this will help :)

Comment: All Works good, i also added if > 24 so it not goes any less then 8. Thanks for Help!)